# Trouble with TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is the code:

```
type Args<State, ActionHandlers, Helpers> = {
    state: State,
    actionHandlers: ActionHandlers,
    helpers?: Helpers
}

type GenericActionHandler<State, Payload> = (state: State, payload: Payload) => Partial<State> | void

type GenericDispatch<State, ActionHandlers> = <
    Key extends keyof ActionHandlers,
    Handler extends ActionHandlers[Key],
    Payload = Handler extends GenericActionHandler<State, infer P> ? P : never
>(type: Key, ...payload: Payload extends undefined ? [] : [Payload]) => void

type GenericHelper<State, ActionHandlers, Payload> = (dispatch: GenericDispatch<State, ActionHandlers>, payload: Payload) => Promise<void> | void

type HelpersRemapped<State, ActionHandlers, Helpers> = {
    [Key in keyof Helpers]: <
        Helper extends Helpers[Key],
        Payload = Helper extends GenericHelper<State, ActionHandlers, infer P> ? P : never 
    >(payload: Payload) => Promise<void> | void
}

const create = <

    State extends {},

    ActionHandlers extends Record<string, GenericActionHandler<State, any>>,

    Helpers extends Record<string, GenericHelper<State, ActionHandlers, any>>

>({ state, actionHandlers, helpers }: Args<State, ActionHandlers, Helpers>) => {

    const dispatch: GenericDispatch<State, ActionHandlers> = (type, ...payload) => { console.log(type, [payload]) };

    type Remap = HelpersRemapped<State, ActionHandlers, Helpers>;

    const helpersRemapped: Partial<Remap> = {}
    for (const key in helpers) {
        helpersRemapped[key] = (payload) => helpers[key](dispatch, payload);
    }

    return {
        dispatch,
        helpers: helpersRemapped as Remap
    };
}

let { dispatch, helpers } = create({
    state: {
        msg: "hi",
        num: 123,
        flag: true
    },
    actionHandlers: {
        SET_MSG: (state, msg: string) => ({ msg }),
        SET_NUM: (state, num: number) => ({ num }),
        SET_FLAG: (state, flag: boolean) => ({ flag })
    },
    helpers: {
        setFlagAsync: async (dispatch, flag: boolean) => { // I don't understand what the problem is here :'(
            await Promise.resolve();
            dispatch("SET_FLAG", flag);
        }
    }
});

helpers.setFlagAsync(true);
dispatch("SET_MSG", "test");
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4B4DKwCGwIBpYDGwAlgPYB2AEpuQCYA2EcS+lE9kzAfFALxQBvAFBRRUJFhwAuKBmx4RYzETJUaDJkhkwVFanUbNci0QAt2nJAH4ZbDpqEBfIUNCQoAcQjkmxAjpI9dUN0STwoAAVMEHpSTFoefgAKCXkZORx8MGjY+JkomLjaAEo+Hii4Ekx6UPkeAB8oADdSYloXN2gvHzg-ABFiJGzgAlNazMJAtQNNRKgUEygAaQgQKAgADxw6JCgAa1XSADNJ1X0NI0Xzw3Wt71pdgLPgzQBtFZAAXWMxSJyivhQa5MW7bB6eby+fy6aYXcbhYjkI4giI8KyRKAyHxNJhCLhJToyD74AB0ZOyhTyf0ptFB912AFc6BAjoiILT0a9PpioK8CrlaJ9SrweC02h1wF1Ib0CHZOPD8E8gjMjNSBXMkrRBsNRjJulCBkNsKMFadlRckFwsv8qfyisLynBSABbQYQFBihJQRqeiXuOWaABKEGdmDAkFopqVsMMLCBFlmgOEv3eqygiP2hxOAeYnxkC1+vxzdJ28fszFTXx+hdEdvigOLmzBu31MpzUZhwNViORcEiaIxWIgOL7i3xFIF+RtJTKkSdrqQ7s9DWarXaziEAHpN1AACrmKAEOAQeRQI5MmEkoQECgSQ-H0-8BaLDLQJv0wSOYyLaNd3bv0tgxvOBIwkXpyAQfBWz8X8XjgU0aBALgrRcIsE2YEtwSA0gQJQMDEUgiEej8dtX0VTs4LjRDkJcfEBHEMJ8GUKY-3wcxy12RxtEQVAyLNGNNFYdDLQdQRULEG9yDvLUjRGUw9WlfptWNMY+NglVLUBAlJVJclp1E+jJKQUhGBJWIEG0yB8FeCciiFKBHAAbnE0ROigYNQzABthI8sMIw7FjKKEjiuGcxYjOAKB2MsXzw3ZKdKmIaoUFiuYBGcX4jhwqAkgizM1gzaLNFKZMayinyQz89lXgOL4tNs+JRKKitas+TVlLk60aWKZzfg3X5j2ABk4HIMSyqgGSdVMasa2arRyo42KIygTBdlixYnKcFxtygABJcgWj2AioGAA8jxPHAzwvKYr0YSL6MmlS2OEhzAXO+QklK0RUmkMayudJAEBkAAiUxiGBmbC3IBlnRkABGAAmABmSHMvoTAgZOuAGQgDbIeY54NJkL7CzQABRXcAH0AFk0A8GQUkYqAAcx-CINEz7mcBhzilRsRyapgA5ABVamGZ+8JodhqApYAIyYDn6Klnm+dEAXKYAMQAGRgemcol-AjnRzHZdIEyT3IRWz2Nnm8cWObicWX5F2ADXjZgJAQHIAgZFWr2CByx7OutjGZFN82aAMqAdt2iaKAAckiplaE0LA6CgAB3UxsBOg8wCdWXGGddNdnMY9MXjpInbKzAM8wYhIoiec3RJY9jPoHEkh66uayD0YkmB9Xtd1iGQ4QbvxoysRnEcbutx3XcIAkY7SAZSLTugNuGXoYAkCvOaSRdt2MY9-2CWxiBu770wB-V2mPFH4GcAkYGeqAA)

If you click through to the TS Playground link above the problem is underlined in red squiggle on line 61 when trying to define a helper method on the helpers object.

```
Type '(dispatch: GenericDispatch<{ msg: string; num: number; flag: boolean; }, Record<string, GenericActionHandler<{ msg: string; num: number; flag: boolean; }, any>>>, flag: boolean) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'GenericHelper<{ msg: string; num: number; flag: boolean; }, { SET_MSG: (state: { msg: string; num: number; flag: boolean; }, msg: string) => { msg: string; }; SET_NUM: (state: { msg: string; num: number; flag: boolean; }, num: number) => { ...; }; SET_FLAG: (state: { ...; }, flag: boolean) => { ...; }; }, any>'.
  Types of parameters 'dispatch' and 'dispatch' are incompatible.
    Types of parameters 'type' and 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'Key' is not assignable to type '"SET_MSG" | "SET_NUM" | "SET_FLAG"'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"SET_MSG" | "SET_NUM" | "SET_FLAG"'.
          Type 'Key' is not assignable to type '"SET_FLAG"'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"SET_FLAG"'.(2322)
```

If you force the code to run it works fine but TypeScript is not satisfied and will not compile.

PS - I know, this is similar to what Redux already does. Sadly I do not have control.

Comment: In order to infer all types, you should refactor your code. `for (const key in helpers) {` should be moved to separate function. You should avoid any kind of mutation in TS if you want to infer types, see this: -->  `helpersRemapped[key]`. Could you please provide all requirements and I will try to help you. In order to make it right, it worth infering every function argument. See this article https://catchts.com/infer-arguments

Comment: I appreciate your offer to help! I did solve my issue though by completely reworking the API for this module into a "type builder" kind of pattern. You're welcome to [give it a look](https://github.com/chevtek/react-state-container/blob/master/src/index.tsx). It's working wonderfully now :D

Comment: Two lines still bother me: `State extends {}` and `const helpers = (helperFunction?.(dispatch) ?? {}) as ReturnType<HelperFunc>`. It is better to use `Record<string, unknown>` instead of `{}`

Comment: @captain-yossarian If you'd like to pull that into a TS playground and clean it up I'm certainly not going to say no haha. I'm definitely not a TypeScript guru by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `actionHandlers` inline within your `create` function.  As you've written your type definition, we expect the keys of the `helpers` to be `Key extends keyof ActionHandlers`.  TypeScript is casting that specifically as one of the key names you defined in the `actionHandlers`, but you are passing `"SET_FLAG"`, which is being interpereted as a `string`. A `string` is too wide a definition to statisfy the `extends keyof ActionHandlers` type.  In other words, `Key extends keyof ActionHandlers` is too *narrow* to be satisfied by a `string` type, so typescript errors.  When I've run into cases like this, I always think "can't typescript recognize that the value is indeed a `keyof` the object??".  I guess not.

In any case, if you define `actionHandlers` before feeding it to `create`, ans cast it `as const`, it solves the problem:

```
const state = {
    msg: "hi",
    num: 123,
    flag: true
}

const actionHandlers = {
    SET_MSG: (stateArg: typeof state, msg: string) => ({ msg }),
    SET_NUM: (stateArg: typeof state, num: number) => ({ num }),
    SET_FLAG: (stateArg: typeof state, flag: boolean) => ({ flag })
} as const;

// Invoking the create function.
let { dispatch, helpers } = create({
    state,
    actionHandlers,
    helpers: {
        setFlagAsync: async (dispatch, flag: boolean) => {
            await Promise.resolve();
            dispatch("SET_FLAG", flag);
        }
    }
});
```

### [Working typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4B4DKwCGwIBpYDGwAlgPYB2AEpuQCYA2EcS+lE9kzAfFALxQBvAFBRRUJFhwAuKBmx4RYzETJUaDJkhkwVFanUbNci0QAt2nJAH4ZbDpqEBfIUNCQoAcQjkmxAjpI9dUN0STwoAAVMEHpSTFoefgAKCXkZORx8MGjY+JkomLjaAEo+Hii4Ekx6UPkeAB8oADdSYloXN2gvHzg-ABFiJGzgAlNazMJAtQNNRKgUEygAaQgQKAgADxw6JCgAa1XSADNJ1X0NI0Xzw3Wt71pdgLPgzQBtFZAAXWMxSJyivhQa5MW7bB6eby+fy6aYXcbhYjkI4giI8KyRKAyHxNJiLLhJToyA4gY6nIIzIxQAB0NOyhTyf3ptFB912AFc6BAjoiIMz0a9PpioK8CrlaJ9SrweC02h1wF1Ib0CHZOPD8E9yRcWIyxXMkrRBsNRjJulCBkNsKM1WTYYYkFwsv8GaKipLynBSABbQYQFAyhJQRr+uXuFWaABKEE9mDAkFo1o1ts0rAss0Bwl+71WUER+0OJzDzE+MgWv1+hZZOyBqeYWa+PzLohd8UBFc2YN2pqVhYTMOBlMRyLgkTRGKxEBxcEWv3xdLF+SdJTKkQ93qQvv9DWarXaziEAHp91AACrmKAEOAQeRQI4cmFUoQECgSc+X6-8BaLDLQduswSOYxFkTftdl-KtIyfOB4wkXpyAQfAuz8YCXjga0aBALgHRccsa1Au5wIgSDoOAWD4IhHo-B7b91T7FDtXQzCXHxARxDCfBlCmED8HMexmCgRxtEQVBqJtLjq14+03UEbCxCfcgXwNC0RlME1FX6Q1LTGETkIpe1AQJeV8BpKk51dZcWLkpBSEYKlYgQAzIHwV5TPiCV+IAbhk0ROigSNozAVtcL8mM417Ti6JTCSuE8xZLOAKAeMsYLY15BdKmIaoUGSuYBGcX4jlIYckjivM1lzRLNFKDNGwSoKoxC3lXmJQVkhcpcpVqiSmtWT59Q05THSZYpPN+PdfkvYA2TgchpJqqBFKNUwG0bCrmBkVakGSuMoEwXZksWRxPL3ErUhwdNFk9JAEBkAAiUxiBu5aoHINlPRkABGAAmABmJ6jnoTBrqgEi2QgJwXBKjjnl087fjQABRY8AH0AFk0A8GQUjCeAgc6UlTvCS6gZgxEECkpIWKJ-jiiehHkYAOQAVRRzGCZxmQ8ZOAn8Bet7ntegAjJhyZY3nqdpxGkYAMQAGRgDGoCx+R2eB+V8bYm8AaBgXSGsq9yBFzXAeppwdt2OKYsPKAAElyBaPZSeBs8LyvM7b3Ie8hEYeKWIWzTuNw-jARd+QKcWbnFihzU7SejaZGqxt12AKWtZgJAQA9mRdozghFb9gaje13XGBoKSWKt635ooAByeKOVoTQsDoKAAHdTGwJ3oDAD0BcYT0c12cxL0xaukmnGrMBbzBiHiiJVx9KlLys+gcSSYbx8bfPRiSG66eluWPEewv17mvKxGcRx14PI9jwgCRHdINl4uAM8l7ZehgCQB8NqpJOU8BtOOcCRwFBuvLepgd57zRoffAN0cASBusNIAA)

Unfortunately when moving the declaration of the argument outside of the function call, we lose the typing on the `state` variable, so I had to explicitly type it.

#### Edit

As I struggling to fall asleep last night, I ended up realizing there's a quicker way from your original code to a solution.  Just use `as const` inline, like this:

```
let { dispatch, helpers } = create({
    state: {
        msg: "hi",
        num: 123,
        flag: true
    },
    actionHandlers: {
        SET_MSG: (state, msg: string) => ({ msg }),
        SET_NUM: (state, num: number) => ({ num }),
        SET_FLAG: (state, flag: boolean) => ({ flag })
    } as const, // <---------------------------------------- here
    helpers: {
        setFlagAsync: async (dispatch, flag: boolean) => { 
            await Promise.resolve();
            dispatch("SET_FLAG", flag);
        }
    }
});
```

That way you can indeed define your function arguments within the function call.

### [Works great](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwM4B4DKwCGwIBpYDGwAlgPYB2AEpuQCYA2EcS+lE9kzAfFALxQBvAFBRRUJFhwAuKBmx4RYzETJUaDJkhkwVFanUbNci0QAt2nJAH4ZbDpqEBfIUNCQoAcQjkmxAjpI9dUN0STwoAAVMEHpSTFoefgAKCXkZORx8MGjY+JkomLjaAEo+Hii4Ekx6UPkeAB8oADdSYloXN2gvHzg-ABFiJGzgAlNazMJAtQNNRKgUEygAaQgQKAgADxw6JCgAa1XSADNJ1X0NI0Xzw3Wt71pdgLPgzQBtFZAAXWMxSJyivhQa5MW7bB6eby+fy6aYXcbhYjkI4giI8KyRKAyHxNJhCLhJToyD74AB0ZOyhTyf0ptFB912AFc6BAjoiILT0a9PpioK8CrlaJ9SrweC02h1wF1Ib0CHZOPD8E8gjMjNSBXMkrRBsNRjJulCBkNsKMFadlRckFwsv8qfyisLynBSABbQYQFBihJQRqeiXuOWaABKEGdmDAkFopqVsMMLCBFlmgOEv3eqygiP2hxOAeYnxkC1+vxzdJ28fszFTXx+hdEdvigOLmzBu31MpzUZhwNViORcEiaIxWIgOL7i3xFIF+RtJTKkSdrqQ7s9DWarXaziEAHpN1AACrmKAEOAQeRQI5MmEkoQECgSQ-H0-8BaLDLQJv0wSOYyLaNd3bv0tgxvOBIwkXpyAQfBWz8X8XjgU0aBALgrRcIsE2YEtwSA0gQJQMDEUgiEej8dtX0VTs4LjRDkJcfEBHEMJ8GUKY-3wcxy12RxtEQVAyLNGNNFYdDLQdQRULEG9yDvLUjRGUw9WlfptWNMY+NglVLUBAlJVJclp1E+jJKQUhGBJWIEG0yB8FeCciiFKBHAAbnE0ROigYNQzABthI8sMIw7FjKKEjiuGcxYjOAKB2MsXzw3ZKdKmIaoUFiuYBGcX4jhwqAkgizM1gzaLNFKZMayinyQz89lXgOL4tNs+JRKKitas+TVlLk60aWKZzfg3X5j2ABk4HIMSyqgGSdVMasa2arRyo42KIygTBdlixYnKcFxtygABJcgWj2AioGAA8jxPHAzwvKYr0YSL6MmlS2OEhzAXO+QklK0RUmkMayudJAEBkAAiUxiGBmbC3IBlnRkABGAAmABmSHMvoTAgZOuAGQgDbIeY54NJkL7CzQABRXcAH0AFk0A8GQUkYqAAcx-CINEz7mcBhzilRsRyapgA5ABVamGZ+8JodhqApYAIyYDn6Klnm+dEAXKYAMQAGRgemcol-AjnRzHZdIEyT3IRWz2NnmNpW3YIshubicWX5F2ADXjZgJAQHIAgZFW32CByx7OutjGZFN82aAMqAdt2iaKAAckiplaE0LA6CgAB3UxsBOg8wCdWXGGddNdnMY9MSTpJXbKzBs8wYhIoiec3RJY9jPoHEkh6uua1D0YkmB9Xtd1iHw4QPvxoysRnEcPutx3XcIAkY7SAZSLTugTuGXoYAkCvOaSXdz2Me9oOCWxiA+8H0xh-V2mPAn4GcAkYGeqAA)

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to understand why it was failing. The weird part though is the `actionHandlers` were totally enjoying strong typing constraints that utilized the state object passed in. But I somehow the added complexity going from action handlers to helpers really blew it up. Because of you though, I completely reworked the API for this module. [Feel free to check it out](https://github.com/chevtek/react-state-container/blob/master/src/index.tsx) :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  I realized there's another way to do this, so I appended my answer

Comment: Ah that's great! Not a fan of having to force the consumer of this module to have to do that, but it is good to know nevertheless!